# onorientation change with jquery not jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I don't want to include jquery mobile library as I have already included jquery and jquery ui. So as per my project this is enough (http request).

So, is there any function just with jquery / javascript / jquery ui for orientation change.

I couldn't find in ui. And I've to keep just 1 script (6 lines of code), so I don't want to include jquery mobile library.

Thank you.

Comment: Mobile functions are only available in jQuery mobile.

Comment: mobile functions are made from javascript, so I think there might be a way to do.

Comment: Copy / paste function from jQuery mobile than

Comment: where can I see that script online?

Comment: If you're worried about requests stacking up, just bundle jQuery, jQuery UI and jQuery Mobile in one JS file, and include that. Boom - One request - all the support you need.

Answer (score -1):

Copy / paste needed function. jQuery mobile online: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/git/jquery.mobile-git.js

Comment: I'm confused what code should I insert. Can you please show me here.